# How to get a specific Entity in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-query

[image]

So, I'm using Room database to store courses and I'm stuck on the method that returns the course with the name(course) that I want because it's always returning null. I have diminished my database to have 2 courses with the course variable as:

As you can see in the picture above, when I try to get the CourseEnt in the Repository with `course = fun`, which I can see below that it exists, it returns a LiveData with a null value instead of the CourseEnt that I wanted.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong or on what should I look into with debugger?

Here's the code:

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "courses_table")
data class CoursesEnt (@PrimaryKey val course: String, 
                                   val location: String, 
                                   val description: String,                           
                                   val difficulty: Double, 
                                   val distance: Double, 
                                   val photos: ListInt, 
                                   val category: String, 
                                   val activities: ListString)//ListString is a type converter that converts a String into a List<String> and vice-versa
```

DAO:

```
@Dao
interface CoursesDao {

   @Query("SELECT * from courses_table ORDER BY course ASC")
    fun getAllCourses(): LiveData<List<CoursesEnt>>

   @Query("SELECT * FROM courses_table WHERE course LIKE :str")
    fun getCourse(str: String):LiveData<CoursesEnt>

   ...
}
```

Repository:

```
class CoursesRepository(private val coursesDao: CoursesDao){

    val allCourses: LiveData<List<CoursesEnt>> = coursesDao.getAllCourses()
    var singleCourse: LiveData<CoursesEnt> = coursesDao.getCourse("")

    @WorkerThread
    fun getCourse(str: String) {

        singleCourse = coursesDao.getCourse(str)
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you observing the new `LiveData` instance that you're putting into the `singleCourse` property with the `getCourse` method? If you start observation before that method runs, it could be that you're still observing the old `LiveData` instance that queried for an empty string.

As a debugging step, I'd try fetching the course in a direct, blocking way (i.e. with an additional method that returns `CoursesEnt?`) inside `getCourse` and looking at the value that you get that way.

Comment: Yes, I am observing the LiveData on my Fragment and I do it after I use getCourse. Regarding the debugging step, as I said in my question what gets returned as null is ```coursesDao.getCourse(str).value``` that I call in my repository, which should return a ```CoursesEnt```

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation, liveData will always return null for straight call, you have to observe LiveData, the result value from Room will be in block. This is some example of usage

```
mViewModel.getAllUsers().observe( this@YourActivity, Observer {
        // it - is all users from DB
    })
```

but if you will call

```
val users = mViewModel.getAllUsers()
```

the result will be null